# Объясните пожалуйста мне эту задачу. Почему h, m, r находятся именно так

Tags: блокчейн

Задача:
Блокчейн (blockchain) переводится как «цепочка блоков». Это способ хранения данных, защищённый от подделки, используемый, в частности, криптовалютой биткоин.

Блокчейн действительно представляет собой последовательность блоков. Каждый блок представляет собой некоторую полезную информацию (в частности, в случае биткоина это список транзакций за определённый период времени — кто кому когда сколько денег передал), снабжённую случайным числом и некоторыми служебными данными, в том числе хэшем — числом, которое по определённой формуле зависит от остальной части блока и хэша предыдущего блока.

Хэш должен быть меньше определённого числа. При этом формула, по которой вычисляется хэш, устроена так, что невозможно получить достаточно маленький хэш иначе, чем перебирая различные значения случайного числа. Поэтому если злоумышленник решит подделать блокчейн (и, допустим, вставить в его середину блок с записью о том, что все люди передают ему все свои деньги), то ему придётся подобрать новое случайное число в новое поддельном блоке и всех последующих (ведь хэш каждого следующего блока зависит от хэша предыдущего), что потребует невозможно больших вычислительных мощностей.

Поэтому блокчейн в целом защищён от подобных атак.

Напишите программу, которая проводит проверку правильности хэшей в модельном блокчейне с простой хэш-функцией.

Блок bn с номером n включает полезную информацию mn, представленную натуральным числом, rn — случайное число от 0 до 255 и hn — хеш (целое число от 0 до 255). У каждого блока хэш вычисляется по формуле hn = 37×(mn+rn+hn-1) (по модулю 256), при вычислении хэша начального блока h0 вместо хэша предыдущего блока берётся ноль.

При этом каждый блок представлен одним числом bn = hn + rn×256 + mn×2562. При этом требуется, чтобы хэш hn был меньше 100.

Формат ввода
На первой строке вводится натуральное число N — количество блоков.
Далее следуют N чисел bn, каждое на отдельной строке.

Формат вывода
Следует вывести номер первого блока, у которого неправильный хэш (не меньше 100 или не совпадает с вычисленным по указанной в условии формуле), или -1, если все хэши в блокчейне правильные. Нумерация блоков идёт с нуля, т. е. они имеют номера от 0 до N-1.

Пример 1
Ввод
5
6122802
14406496
15230209
2541121
1758741
           Вывод: -1
Пример 2
Ввод    Вывод
5
1865535
13479687
16689153
1839958
5214020
           Вывод: 3

Comment: И в чём проблема?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, именно переменных h, m, r в этой задаче вообще нет. hn - это не произведение h*n, а просто двухбуквенное название переменной. Во-вторых, велечины здесь вычисляются именно так, потому что так решил автор задачи. В реальном блокчейне принципы те же, но конкретные формулы сложнее.

Comment: И ещё - вопрос ну вот вообще никак не относится к тэгу python.

Comment: @Xander за тэг сорян, я впервые на этом форуме. Мне нужно узнать почему h, m, r вычисляются таким способом и при чём тут 256

Comment: Я уже сказал - конкретные формулы и коэффициенты такие просто потому, что так решил автор задачи. Это как вот если вы откроете задачник по арифметике, и там будет задача - у Васи 4 яблока, а у Коли - 7. Вы же не будете спрашивать - откуда взялись числа 4 и 7, и почему мальчиков зовут именно Вася и Коля. Просто так придумал автор задачи. Можно было брать хэш не по модулю 256, а по модулю какого-то другого числа. Тогда немножко поменялись бы другие числа в задаче, но суть бы от этого не изменилась.

Answer (score 0):

```
last_h = 0
for i in range(int(input())):
    block = int(input())
    now_h = block % 256 # "первый разряд" от умножения на 256
    r = (block // 256) % 256 # "средний разряд" от умножения на 256
    m = block // 256 ** 2 # "крайний разряд" от умножения на 256
    calc_h = (37 * (m + r + last_h)) % 256 # хеш по формуле
    if calc_h != now_h or calc_h > 100:
        print(i)
        break
    last_h = calc_h
else:
    print(-1)
```

Я кажется понял, это работает как с разрядами десятков:
bn = hn + rn * 256 + mn * 256 ** 2,
мы сдвигаем каждый элемент на разряд.
например (пример в нашей любимой 10ричной системе исчисления):
n = first + second * 10 + third * (10 ** 2)
n = str(first) + str(second) + str(third)
т.е. и в первом и во втором случае они идут друг за другом. Поэтому мы и можем вытаскивать по разряду из блока

Comment: а это точно ответ на заданный вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Вот такие, на мой взгляд соображения.

```
b0 = h0 + r0*256 + m0 * 256^2
h0 = (37 * (m0 + r0 + h(n-1))) % 256
```

Нам сообщают по очереди b числа и мы должны вычисляя хеш текущего блока и потом используя предыдущий хеш и полезные данные текущего блока вычислять снова хеш и он должен быть равен текущему.

Начнем с первого b0

```
b0 = h0 + r0*256 + m0 * 256^2
```

Найдем h0. Для этого возьмем его по модулю % 256

```
b0 % 256 = (h0 + r0*256 +m0*256^2) % 256
```

Важно что вот это r0*256 % 256 = 0, т.к остаток от деления на 256 = 0, так-как это число точно на него делится (ведь мы на него умножили).

```
(m0 * 256^2) % 256 тоже = 0 (аналогично)
```

Теперь b0 % 256 = h0 % 256, но мы также знаем что h0 это число меньше 100 и из этого следует что h0 % 256 = h0

Таким образом мы нашли хеш для b0

```
h0 = b0 % 256
```

Теперь найдем r0, для этого рассмотрим вот такое выражение.

```
(b0 // 256) % 256
```

здесь // - это целочисленное деление, т.е. оставляем только целую часть.

```
(b0 // 256) % 256 = ((h0 + r0*256 +m0*256^2) // 256) % 256
```

h0 // 256 = 0, т.к. h0 < 100, т.е при делении будет 0,XXXXX или 0 если целую часть рассмотреть.

```
r0 * 256 // 256 = r0

m0 * 256 ^ 2/256 = m0 * 256
```

Теперь у нас:

```
(b0 // 256) % 256 = (0 + r0 + m0 * 256) % 256 = r0 % 256 + 0
```

т.к. (m0 * 256) % 256 = 0

Но мы знаем что r0 это число 0 до 255, т.е. r0 % 256 = r0

Получаем:

```
  r0 = (b0 // 256) % 256
```

Теперь найдем m0. Для чего сделаем такую операцию

```
b0 // 256 ^ 2 = (h0 + r0*256 + m0 * 256^2) // 256^2
```

Тут будут такие рассуждения (аналогичные предыдущим в чем-то):

```
h0 // 256^2 =0, так-как h0 < 100
r0 * 256 // 256^2 = r0 // 256 = 0, т.к. r0 < 255
m0 * 256^2 / 256^2 = m0
```

и по итогу:

```
m0 = b0 // 256 ^2
```

Теперь у нас есть m0, r0, h0 (текущий хеш блока)

Вычислим хеш повторно для проверки, используя m0, r0 и предыдущий хеш(-1), по условиям, предыдущий хеш нулевого блока = 0

```
hh = (37 * (m0 + r0 + h(n-1))) % 256
```

На самом деле hh это и должен быть наш h0, но надо проверить.

```
hh = (37 * (m0 + r0)) % 256
```

Все данные у нас есть и после вычисления мы получим хеш hh и он должен быть равным h0, что мы и сравним.

Далее повторяем вычисления для следующего блока